# Android Studio use gradle offline

Tags: android

I had to install Android studio on offline machine.
After I create a project, I get bunch of errors, referred to Gradle. How can I make it build offline?
P.S. I'm completely new to Android and java. Help me, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, I've tried use offline option in settings, but I get "Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_UnitTestApkCopy'... " and so on.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly it asks me to 'Disable offline mode and sync!'

Comment: You need to be online for initial sync

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly yup, it's clear, but I'm restricted to turn my target machine online even to sync. Are there any ways to sync gradle through downloading some files directly from the internet and then copy it somewhere on the target machine?