# firebase jobdispatcher- I can't add dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle

I have problem w adding dependency for firebase jobdispatcher, I have tried back and forth with my gradle file, I have installed Google Play service in my android SDK and still I can't compile this depencency.

Here is my gradle file -app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.project"

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'

    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'
}
```

and here project level

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: android studio tools>firebase will help a lot with configuration issues. It automates the process. Not sure about jobdispacher though

Comment: What is the error message when you build?  Current version is `jobdispatcher:0.8.5`

Comment: Error:Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Sounds like a network issue.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42516117/4815718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

try this in project-level build.gradle