# gradle sync failed, read timeout error in android studio 3.3.1 for sample hello world app in

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, connection-timeout

connection timeout error in gradle sync, in android studio 3.3 for sample hello world app in.
Earlier it was working with no proxy set in http setting in android studio settings.
I have tried other solution from stack overflow. looks like gradle can't download from all urls.
now reinstalling studio after completely uninstalling it.
**Update**
after reinstalling the problem persists. 
[image]

SOMETIME build clean from GUI does not do anything at all.

**Project level Build.gradle file**
**     Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**

**App level build.graldle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**Update**

***After formatting my windows 10 and freshly installed development tools, it now throws Gradle Sync Failed: Read timeout error***

Comment: if you are reinstalling android studio then what exactly is the question ?. Can you post your build.gradle file here ?

Comment: This is a network problem, check your internet connection. Maybe some firewall is blocking you.

Comment: @Umair, please see my update.

Comment: @VikasPandey as henry said it's a internet connection issue. please check your connection or firewall. Moreover if you want to work offline then follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516117/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-connection-timed-out-connect

Comment: @umair, posted my build.gradle file

Comment: @Henry,  yes, it looks more like a network issue, i have tested with my mobile hotspot network and my network administrator had disabled firewall too, still not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: that worked for me

setting -
language and framework -
kotlin -
update kotlin plugin version -
restart computer -
run android studio and now it works and it ran faster
[image: Update kotlin plugin version]

tried

1. using local gradle repository
2. changing no proxy in setting-http
3. uninstalling, reinstalling, formatting my laptop
   after 2 days:

i tried to see a kotlin in setting. then there was an update for kotlin,

Answer (score 0):

Its Network issue fails to build pass `offline` argument in `Gradle`

Try `./gradlew tasks --offline`

For run Android project in `offline` mode visit **GRADLE CLI** docs : [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html)

**Android Studio**

In Android, studio can make `Gradle` to build your project in `offline` mode options :

`Settings` -- `Build, Execution, Deployment` -- `Build tools` -- `Gradle`

[Gradle Offline Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies/32173577#32173577)

Comment: for offline to work, it must have been able to run successfully in the past, that never happened to me.