# Fail to sync Gradle Project and show message `Read time out`

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

when i want to sync the realm to my project, the android studio show me whit `Read timed out` or say that compile is not support but my project have no code whit compile.

i tried to update the version of the realm, but still fail to work
when i add the below code

my app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

my project level build.gradle

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
```

the Android Studio show Read time out
and when i update the realm version to 3.0.0
and the Android Studio show `the compile is abandon`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516117/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-connection-timed-out-connect)

Comment: well, it can't solve my problem.

Comment: emmm, the problem was soluted when i update the realm plugin to v4.0.0.```classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.0.0"```