# Build Gradle Conncetion time out

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I trying to sync Gradle I got this Error : `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connent` so then i check gradle settings to work offline . i got this error `No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1 available for offline mode.`
 i know its need to download this manually but where i can download it in 
  [1]: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/ or somewhere else? ( I already downloaded the Gradle latest version ) Right installing path is `C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its for some bug of android studio .So We should re-open android studio in some cases or disconnect our device to internet also i disconnect my laptop to network and its got me Maven error ! In this step its told me about missing build tools 27.0.1 so now im downloading this and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your PC/Laptop to network and then unchecked Work Offline and then build again.Gradle automatically download all files which will necesssary for your project.

Comment: My laptop is already connected to internet. But its still didnt download that file and give me connection error ! i also checked up my firewall  to ensure is AndroidStudio or one of its services is Blocked or not so its not blocked ! I thinks its for some bug of android studio . i disconnect my laptop to network and its got me Maven error ! In this step its told me about missing build tools 27.0.1 so i now im downloading this

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck in this problem because of the network issue. You can solve this issue by trying the offline argument.
Try `./gradlew tasks --offline`

Or the another solution is given at the link: you can enable the offline mode:
[How to configure gradle to work "offline" (using cached dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies/32173577#32173577)

Comment: Hmm .  I thinks its for some bug of android studio . i disconnect my laptop to network and its got me Maven error ! In this step its told me about missing build tools 27.0.1 so now im downloading this

Answer (score 0):

In gradle-wraper.properties change the download link to this
distributionUrl=https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip