# Can I add firebase sdk into my android studio offline?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, dependencies, implementation

I need to use firbase for my android project. But I don’t have a internet connection in my PC. Can I download the firebase sdk then add it to my android studio mannually?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a project, reference all the SDKs you want to use in its build.gradle, and do a build.  All the maven dependencies will be downloaded and cached by gradle (in the .gradle folder in your home directory).  Future builds will use the cached dependencies.  You can go further and indicate that the [gradle build can be designated "offline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies), which means that gradle won't even check to see if there are any updates, and only use the cache.

This is going to apply to all maven-based dependencies, and does not just apply to Firebase.