# Gradle build jitpack error android studio

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, jitpack

I'm having problem with Gradle build since 2 days when I am build Gradle.

Error:

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.9.7/crashlytics-2.9.7.pom'. Received status code 522 from server: Origin Connection Time-out Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Can anyone have any solution for this?

I have tried below commands/steps for the resolved issue:

- Invalidate catches/Restarts
- delete .gradle file and try again
- delete .gradle and .android file from root and try again
- try with offline sync

But Still not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Go To Studio Preference--> GRadle--> then disable offline work and apply

Comment: please add your gradle contents.

Comment: @KishanMaurya I have tried but not working

Comment: Check you internet connection may be it's not working.

Comment: @AnasMehar Internet working properly.

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71603699/12272687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is issue with jitpack DNS that came up recently. Its described [in this issue](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/3973), along with workaround solutions.

Comment: Hi Kuba. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Best Regards.

Answer (score 6):

Issue has been resolve with below solution.

Just add 'www' on Main Gradle file.

```
 repositories {
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }

}
```

Source: https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/3973

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this happens issue of a network problem,

If your network working properly then try with **Invalidate catches/Restarts** from your file menu

Or then also work then start to work offline
Please follow below command to set your Gradle offline

```
./gradlew tasks --offline
```

**Or** else you can follow steps from bellow answer

[Answer for offline gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies/32173577#32173577)

Comment: Turning off gradle repository synchronization is not tackling the real problem. This cannot be even considered as a hackish solution.