# How to solve Gradle sync failed?

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I create a project in Android studio it asked me for Gradle to download .

How can I work offline ?

Comment: see this for offline mode [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio for windows:

Goto File-> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tool -> Gradle

Here Check the Offline Work checkbox and press ok

For Mac:

Goto File-> Other Settings -> Preferences for New Projects -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tool -> Gradle

Here Check the Offline Work checkbox and press ok