# Can I prevent the gradle from downloading jars by pre-downloading these jar files to local?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am a new programmer to Gradle and Minecraft modding.
I tried to set up the Minecraft forge **build.gradle** file using command

```
./gradlew genVSCodeRuns
```

in the command line of VSCode. Every time it failed in the process of downloading two required files with this kind of error message:

```
> Could not download icu4j-66.1.jar (com.ibm.icu:icu4j:66.1)
  > Could not get resource 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/66.1/icu4j-66.1.jar'.
     > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 12,935,630; received: 6,397,856)
```

As I thought this was due to the internet problem, I tried to download the two required jar files to local and saved them in the libs folder. However, as I tried to implement them before Gradle started to download them automatically using the following script, Gradle kept on downloading them.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir:'libs',includes:['*jar'])
}
```

And I am now wondering what is the correct script to use these downloaded jar files as cache and prevent the **build.gradle** from downloading them again.

I viewed similar questions and do not know **where** to place my **cache files**. Only if I place the cache files correctly can I use the **offline** mode of Gradle to build the project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force gradle to NOT to download dependencies (and load them from it's cache instead)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094638/how-to-force-gradle-to-not-to-download-dependencies-and-load-them-from-its-cac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the solution by myself.

The goal is to add the downloaded file to local cache to order Gradle to use this file cache instead of re-downloading the file from the internet.

Before doing this, we need to make sure that **the size of file is same as the required size**. Because of my poor internet connection, I once downloaded only 6mb while the true size was 18mb.

To add this to local cache, follow the steps below.

Firstly, add an environmental variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME`.

Then, the **jar file caches** will be stored at path:

```
/%GRADLE_USER_HOME%/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/$package$/$project$/$version$/$sha1$/$proj-ver.jar$/
```

For example, for `icu4j-66.1.jar` from URL 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/66.1/icu4j-66.1.jar' will be stored at the following path:

```
%GRADLE_USER_HOME%/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.ibm.icu/icu4j/66.1/$sha1$/icu4j-66.1.jar
```

After that, we need to fetch the sha1 code. We can implement the Gradle code from https://gist.github.com/dagezi/9594839#file-calcsha1-gradle in **build.gradle** by creating a new task and print out the fetched sha1 code.

Then, run **build.gradle** again, and the cached file will be implemented automatically. (There is no need to use offline mode)