# gradle sync ok, but cant't build the project

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43svS.png)

Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

gradle sync done very well but when build the project the (online or offline) an error occure
can any body help me

Comment: try to invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same proplem when I try to make okhttp request but I solve this proplem 
Try/gradlew tasks --offline

Or, to make android studio run in offline mode, follow the instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32173577/1043518