# Make a Gradle project work without an internet connection

Tags: gradle, offline

Given a Gradle project, that has:

- Runtime/Compile-time dependencies.
- Source/Javadoc Jars of dependencies.
- Gradle plugins.

All of which are retrieved from the internet.

How can I download all of these online dependencies to a local folder, and then use them locally in a Gradle project?

The goal is to end up with a project that doesn't rely on an internet connection at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure gradle to work "offline" (using cached dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a one-time download of your required dependencies to a local folder, and add a local "maven repo", besides the dependencies, it should also work for sources.

```
repositories {
   maven {
       url 'file://C:/LocalRepo'
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you download all these dependencies? Also, what you showed doesn't work for plugins.

Comment: When you run build with Gradle, it downloads the dependencies to a local folder and uses it from there.
As of plugins, I don't know of a solution, will edit it out.

Comment: Usually, this is being called `mavenLocal()` - or `flatDir` for AAR.