# Cant Run app on android studio when offline

Tags: gradle, build

Im having difficulties running my app while offline it requires me to have internet data for the file to build and run. How can i enable it to run on offline mode on mac os.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure gradle to work "offline" (using cached dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.