# How should I avoid downloading gradle.zip when I want to build my neo4j graph-data-science-master project?

Tags: gradle, offline-mode, gradle-wrapper

I am new to remote development and feel quite confused as the remote device I use is at offline status.

I followed the README doc of the [repository](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science) and skipped installing SDKMAN(as it is a manegement tool for jdks so I thought it is unnecessary). Then I met problem building it. I ran `./gradlew TASK` command in the ternimal and it started downloading gradle. But the remote device I use is totally offline, no network at all.

Besides, there is a small button with gradle icon on the right-top corner, saying `Load Gradle Changes \n Gradle project structrue has been changed. Load changes into interlliJ IDEA to make it work correctly`. If I click it, it starts downloading gradle.

I have no idea why it downloads gradle, I have gradle on my remote device.

I have installed gradle in the location `/opt/gradle/bin/gradle` and it works with IDEA. Is there any method to config `gradle` manually to avoid downloading gradle.zip? Thank you very much!

What I've tried:
I downloaded gradle.zip and unzipped it to the workspace. Then I got a folder named gradle-8.0.2, and I renamed it to gradle. At the first time I had done this, downloading was skipped. But the next time I tried building again, it started downloading again.

What I am expecting:
I am expecting a solution that allows me to build and run tests without network. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried configuring offline mode? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32173484/4161471 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-offline.html

Comment: You can install Gradle beforehand and not use the Gradle wrapper at all.
Basically, replace all documented instructions containing "./gradlew" with "gradle" and that should work.

Comment: @aSemy Thank you, I've tried this method. It seems a correct way but I met another problem about missing dependencies. I think I can handle it myself.

Comment: @fbiville thanks with your solution. But gradle stucks at the initializing process. The progress bar value is 0 all the time. I've installed gradle but it doesn't work and I have no idea

Comment: I see, you'll need to resolve all the dependencies online once, and then you should be able to build offline: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-offline-mode