Gradle Offline in Android Studio?
Hello Everyone out at StackOverFlow
I wish you all be healthy.
My Question is there any way to make Gradle work Totally Offline?
I tried Catching it or downloading complete gradle repo offline but not worked.
Now I want to find a way to use that as internet is very bad in Afghanistan.

refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies

please refrain from greetings etc in question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
